# What RPMs do I need for timeconfig?

Tags: configuration, rpm, centos, setuptools

I've got `setuptools` set up and have read through the list of what's in `/etc/setuptools.d`

I'm interested in installing `timeconfig` as well, but I only need the TUI version (no GUI). Which RPMs do I need? (I'll be including these RPMs in a CentOS ISO installation)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the package system-config-date.

In CentOS it is not installed by default but you can install it by typing

```
sudo yum install system-config-date
```

and that should get you the tui tool you need which you can run by typing

```
sudo system-config-date
```

Answer (score 3):

If you can make a reasonable guess as to where a command is located, yum can tell you what package it's in.

```
# yum resolvedep /usr/bin/timeconfig
No Package Found for /usr/bin/timeconfig

# yum resolvedep /usr/sbin/timeconfig
0:system-config-date-1.8.12-4.el5.noarch
```

Comment: This'll be very helpful in the future, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of yum resolvedep you can use yum provides. It may take a while to populate all the file lists but it's very handy.

```
# yum provides *bin/timeconfig
Loaded plugins: downloadonly, rhnplugin
system-config-date-1.8.12-5.el5.noarch : A graphical interface for modifying system date and time
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-updates-5
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/timeconfig



system-config-date-1.8.12-4.el5.noarch : A graphical interface for modifying system date and time
Repo        : rhel-x86_64-server-updates-5
Matched from:
Filename    : /usr/sbin/timeconfig
```